# JavaScript function not being invoked after setting dropdown value in Telerik

Tags: .net, vb.net, telerik

I am using Telerik WebAii Framework (VB.net).  After calling SelectDropDown to change the value of a dropdown box, the associated javascript event is not being called.

I've had a look at [this post](http://www.telerik.com/automated-testing-tools/community/forums/test-studio-express/general-discussions/onsubmit-event-doesn-t-invoke.aspx) but their suggestion does not fix my problem.   I've tried invoking the script directly but I keep receiving exceptions.

Does anybody know a way around this?

The javascript event is onchange -

code:

```
handleSelectOnChange(this);handleRequiredFields(this.value);
```

vb.net code:

```
Private xBrowser As Browser
Private f As New FrameInfo

f = xBrowser.Frames("appContentFrame").FrameInfo

Dim searchType As Element = xBrowser.Frames(f).Find.ByName("myName")

xBrowser.Frames(f).Actions.SelectDropDown(searchType, "mySearchValue")

xBrowser.Manager.Desktop.KeyBoard.KeyPress(ArtOfTest.WebAii.Win32.KeyBoard.KeysFromString("Tab"), 150, 1)
```

this throws an exception:

```
xBrowser.Frames(f).Actions.InvokeScript("handleSelectOnChange(this);handleRequiredFields(this.value);")
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out - using InvokeEvent instead of InvokeScript 
fired the event i was expecting.

```
xBrowser.Frames(f).Actions.InvokeEvent(searchType, ScriptEventType.OnChange)
```

Thanks.